# Why std::sample is not constexpr?

Tags: c++, random, c++20

I know that c++11 PRNG in `<random>` such as `std::mt19937`  are not usable in compile time, but  access the `__TIME__` preprocessor macro to implement the `constexpr` version of PRNG is possible, why [`std::sample`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample)/[`std::ranges::sample`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/sample) is not `constexpr` even in C++20?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://mklimenko.github.io/english/2018/06/04/constexpr-random/

Comment: Just because something is possible, doesn't mean it should be in the standard library.

Comment: I'd wager it's just that nobody proposed making them `constexpr`

Comment: Access to `__TIME__` macro might not give desired precision. It could be hard to predict when value changes because many factors like file dependencies, multiple inclusions, pre-compiled headers, how many time the file is actually parsed... **And above all, if the function is called multiple times, would it return the same or different values.** As far as I know, the standard does not define many of those details so the behavior of the function would be at most implementation specified behavior and in this case, it would be essentially useless.